# Problems installing QGIS 2.2 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu

After major upgrade to 14.04 I tried to purge and reinstall QGIS.

Unfortunately I get and error (full listing below) and cannot finish clean installation.

Information in the log points errors to appear with pyspatialite and/or python-pyspatialite but I cannot find any solution to this issue.

Also - QGIS actually manages to start after installation but points to another error with PyQGIS this time:

[image]

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

```
rdk@hal:~$ sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  grass grass-core grass-doc grass-gui libmotif-common libmrm4
  libopenscenegraph99 libosgearth3 libosgearthannotation3 libosgearthfeatures3
  libosgearthqt3 libosgearthsymbology3 libosgearthutil3 libqgis-analysis2.2.0
  libqgis-core2.2.0 libqgis-gui2.2.0 libqgis-networkanalysis2.2.0
  libqgisgrass2.2.0 libqgispython2.2.0 libspatialindex3 libtcl8.5 libtk8.5
  libuil4 libxm4 osgearth-data python-opengl python-pyspatialite
  python-qgis-common qgis-common qgis-plugin-globe qgis-plugin-globe-common
  qgis-plugin-grass-common qgis-providers qgis-providers-common tcl8.5 tk8.5
Suggested packages:
  grass-dev e00compr avce00 gnuplot gpstrans python-rpy2 xml2 grass-dev-doc
  openscenegraph libgle3 tcl-tclreadline
The following NEW packages will be installed
  grass grass-core grass-doc grass-gui libmotif-common libmrm4
  libopenscenegraph99 libosgearth3 libosgearthannotation3 libosgearthfeatures3
  libosgearthqt3 libosgearthsymbology3 libosgearthutil3 libqgis-analysis2.2.0
  libqgis-core2.2.0 libqgis-gui2.2.0 libqgis-networkanalysis2.2.0
  libqgisgrass2.2.0 libqgispython2.2.0 libspatialindex3 libtcl8.5 libtk8.5
  libuil4 libxm4 osgearth-data python-opengl python-pyspatialite python-qgis
  python-qgis-common qgis qgis-common qgis-plugin-globe
  qgis-plugin-globe-common qgis-plugin-grass qgis-plugin-grass-common
  qgis-providers qgis-providers-common tcl8.5 tk8.5
0 to upgrade, 39 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 62.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 235 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/ trusty/main qgis-providers-common all 2.2.0-2~trusty1 [1,539 kB]
Get:2 http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty/universe libmotif-common all 2.3.4-5 [11.8 kB]
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/ trusty/main libqgis-core2.2.0 amd64 2.2.0-2~trusty1 [2,607 kB]
Get:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/ trusty/main libqgis-gui2.2.0 amd64 2.2.0-2~trusty1 [1,913 kB]
Get:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/ trusty/main qgis-providers amd64 2.2.0-2~trusty1 [1,770 kB]
Get:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/ trusty/main libosgearth3 amd64 2.5.0+dfsg-3~trusty1 [775 kB]
Get:7 http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty/universe libxm4 amd64 2.3.4-5 [967 kB]
Get:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/ trusty/main libosgearthsymbology3 amd64 2.5.0+dfsg-3~trusty1 [244 kB]
Get:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/ trusty/main libosgearthfeatures3 amd64 2.5.0+dfsg-3~trusty1 [246 kB]
Get:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/ trusty/main libosgearthannotation3 amd64 2.5.0+dfsg-3~trusty1 [172 kB]
Get:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/ trusty/main libosgearthutil3 amd64 2.5.0+dfsg-3~trusty1 [633 kB]
Get:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/ trusty/main libosgearthqt3 amd64 2.5.0+dfsg-3~trusty1 [176 kB]
Get:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/ trusty/main libqgis-analysis2.2.0 amd64 2.2.0-2~trusty1 [930 kB]
Get:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/ trusty/main libqgis-networkanalysis2.2.0 amd64 2.2.0-2~trusty1 [794 kB]
Get:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/ trusty/main libqgisgrass2.2.0 amd64 2.2.0-2~trusty1 [844 kB]
Get:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/ trusty/main libqgispython2.2.0 amd64 2.2.0-2~trusty1 [789 kB]
Get:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/ trusty/main osgearth-data all 2.5.0+dfsg-3~trusty1 [3,946 kB]
Get:18 http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty/universe libmrm4 amd64 2.3.4-5 [56.2 kB]
Get:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/ trusty/main python-qgis-common all 2.2.0-2~trusty1 [2,882 kB]
Get:20 http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty/universe libspatialindex3 amd64 1.8.1-2 [218 kB]
Get:21 http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty/main libtcl8.5 amd64 8.5.15-2ubuntu1 [684 kB]
Get:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/ trusty/main python-qgis amd64 2.2.0-2~trusty1 [2,671 kB]
Get:23 http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty/main libtk8.5 amd64 8.5.15-2ubuntu3 [641 kB]
Get:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/ trusty/main qgis-common all 2.2.0-2~trusty1 [6,335 kB]
Get:25 http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty/universe libuil4 amd64 2.3.4-5 [126 kB]
Get:26 http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty/universe grass-core amd64 6.4.3-3 [7,199 kB]
Get:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/ trusty/main qgis amd64 2.2.0-2~trusty1 [4,890 kB]
Get:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/ trusty/main qgis-plugin-globe-common all 2.2.0-2~trusty1 [780 kB]
Get:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/ trusty/main qgis-plugin-globe amd64 2.2.0-2~trusty1 [856 kB]
Get:30 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/ trusty/main qgis-plugin-grass-common all 2.2.0-2~trusty1 [1,198 kB]
Get:31 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/ trusty/main qgis-plugin-grass amd64 2.2.0-2~trusty1 [1,508 kB]
Get:32 http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty/universe grass-doc all 6.4.3-3 [6,303 kB]
Get:33 http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty/main tcl8.5 amd64 8.5.15-2ubuntu1 [13.9 kB]
Get:34 http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty/main tk8.5 amd64 8.5.15-2ubuntu3 [12.0 kB]
Get:35 http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty/universe python-opengl all 3.0.2-1 [364 kB]
Get:36 http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty/universe grass-gui amd64 6.4.3-3 [1,818 kB]
Get:37 http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty/universe libopenscenegraph99 amd64 3.2.0~rc1-4 [5,283 kB]
Get:38 http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty/universe python-pyspatialite amd64 3.0.1-4 [29.4 kB]
Get:39 http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu/ trusty/universe grass all 6.4.3-3 [6,148 B]
Fetched 62.2 MB in 5s (10.8 MB/s)
Extract templates from packages: 100%
Selecting previously unselected package libmotif-common.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gettext' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'texinfo' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 500015 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libmotif-common_2.3.4-5_all.deb ...
Unpacking libmotif-common (2.3.4-5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxm4:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libxm4_2.3.4-5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxm4:amd64 (2.3.4-5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmrm4:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libmrm4_2.3.4-5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmrm4:amd64 (2.3.4-5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libspatialindex3:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libspatialindex3_1.8.1-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libspatialindex3:amd64 (1.8.1-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libtcl8.5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libtcl8.5_8.5.15-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libtcl8.5:amd64 (8.5.15-2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libtk8.5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libtk8.5_8.5.15-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libtk8.5:amd64 (8.5.15-2ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libuil4:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libuil4_2.3.4-5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libuil4:amd64 (2.3.4-5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package qgis-providers-common.
Preparing to unpack .../qgis-providers-common_2.2.0-2~trusty1_all.deb ...
Unpacking qgis-providers-common (2.2.0-2~trusty1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libqgis-core2.2.0.
Preparing to unpack .../libqgis-core2.2.0_2.2.0-2~trusty1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqgis-core2.2.0 (2.2.0-2~trusty1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libqgis-gui2.2.0.
Preparing to unpack .../libqgis-gui2.2.0_2.2.0-2~trusty1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqgis-gui2.2.0 (2.2.0-2~trusty1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package qgis-providers.
Preparing to unpack .../qgis-providers_2.2.0-2~trusty1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking qgis-providers (2.2.0-2~trusty1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package grass-core.
Preparing to unpack .../grass-core_6.4.3-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking grass-core (6.4.3-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package grass-doc.
Preparing to unpack .../grass-doc_6.4.3-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking grass-doc (6.4.3-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package tcl8.5.
Preparing to unpack .../tcl8.5_8.5.15-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking tcl8.5 (8.5.15-2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package tk8.5.
Preparing to unpack .../tk8.5_8.5.15-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking tk8.5 (8.5.15-2ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-opengl.
Preparing to unpack .../python-opengl_3.0.2-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-opengl (3.0.2-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package grass-gui.
Preparing to unpack .../grass-gui_6.4.3-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking grass-gui (6.4.3-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libopenscenegraph99.
Preparing to unpack .../libopenscenegraph99_3.2.0~rc1-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libopenscenegraph99 (3.2.0~rc1-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libosgearth3.
Preparing to unpack .../libosgearth3_2.5.0+dfsg-3~trusty1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libosgearth3 (2.5.0+dfsg-3~trusty1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libosgearthsymbology3.
Preparing to unpack .../libosgearthsymbology3_2.5.0+dfsg-3~trusty1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libosgearthsymbology3 (2.5.0+dfsg-3~trusty1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libosgearthfeatures3.
Preparing to unpack .../libosgearthfeatures3_2.5.0+dfsg-3~trusty1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libosgearthfeatures3 (2.5.0+dfsg-3~trusty1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libosgearthannotation3.
Preparing to unpack .../libosgearthannotation3_2.5.0+dfsg-3~trusty1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libosgearthannotation3 (2.5.0+dfsg-3~trusty1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libosgearthutil3.
Preparing to unpack .../libosgearthutil3_2.5.0+dfsg-3~trusty1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libosgearthutil3 (2.5.0+dfsg-3~trusty1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libosgearthqt3.
Preparing to unpack .../libosgearthqt3_2.5.0+dfsg-3~trusty1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libosgearthqt3 (2.5.0+dfsg-3~trusty1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libqgis-analysis2.2.0.
Preparing to unpack .../libqgis-analysis2.2.0_2.2.0-2~trusty1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqgis-analysis2.2.0 (2.2.0-2~trusty1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libqgis-networkanalysis2.2.0.
Preparing to unpack .../libqgis-networkanalysis2.2.0_2.2.0-2~trusty1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqgis-networkanalysis2.2.0 (2.2.0-2~trusty1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libqgisgrass2.2.0.
Preparing to unpack .../libqgisgrass2.2.0_2.2.0-2~trusty1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqgisgrass2.2.0 (2.2.0-2~trusty1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libqgispython2.2.0.
Preparing to unpack .../libqgispython2.2.0_2.2.0-2~trusty1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqgispython2.2.0 (2.2.0-2~trusty1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package osgearth-data.
Preparing to unpack .../osgearth-data_2.5.0+dfsg-3~trusty1_all.deb ...
Unpacking osgearth-data (2.5.0+dfsg-3~trusty1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-qgis-common.
Preparing to unpack .../python-qgis-common_2.2.0-2~trusty1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-qgis-common (2.2.0-2~trusty1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-pyspatialite.
Preparing to unpack .../python-pyspatialite_3.0.1-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-pyspatialite (3.0.1-4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../python-qgis_2.2.0-2~trusty1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-qgis (2.2.0-2~trusty1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-qgis_2.2.0-2~trusty1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspatialite/dump.py', which is also in package python-pyspatialite 3.0.1-4
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Selecting previously unselected package qgis-common.
Preparing to unpack .../qgis-common_2.2.0-2~trusty1_all.deb ...
Unpacking qgis-common (2.2.0-2~trusty1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package qgis.
Preparing to unpack .../qgis_2.2.0-2~trusty1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking qgis (2.2.0-2~trusty1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package qgis-plugin-globe-common.
Preparing to unpack .../qgis-plugin-globe-common_2.2.0-2~trusty1_all.deb ...
Unpacking qgis-plugin-globe-common (2.2.0-2~trusty1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package qgis-plugin-globe.
Preparing to unpack .../qgis-plugin-globe_2.2.0-2~trusty1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking qgis-plugin-globe (2.2.0-2~trusty1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package qgis-plugin-grass-common.
Preparing to unpack .../qgis-plugin-grass-common_2.2.0-2~trusty1_all.deb ...
Unpacking qgis-plugin-grass-common (2.2.0-2~trusty1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package grass.
Preparing to unpack .../archives/grass_6.4.3-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking grass (6.4.3-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package qgis-plugin-grass.
Preparing to unpack .../qgis-plugin-grass_2.2.0-2~trusty1_amd64.deb ...
Adding 'diversion of /usr/bin/qgis to /usr/bin/qgis.bin by qgis-plugin-grass'
Adding 'diversion of /usr/bin/qbrowser to /usr/bin/qbrowser.bin by qgis-plugin-grass'
Unpacking qgis-plugin-grass (2.2.0-2~trusty1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.46ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for doc-base (0.10.5) ...
Processing 1 added doc-base file...
Registering documents with scrollkeeper...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-qgis_2.2.0-2~trusty1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Seeing the [available packages](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntugis-unstable?field.series_filter=trusty) for Trusty, I would think that the Ubuntugis repository is not  ready yet for full support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until Ubuntugis supports all required packages (especially GDAL and spatialite), it is recommended to use the official QGIS repository:

https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#ubuntu

It works for me, except for the exotic drivers that require special gdal packages. These will be available from ubuntugis again once they are finished.

Comment: Thank you. That solved the issue. When will be the good time to switch to `ubuntugis` repo?

Comment: Keep an eye on https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntugis-unstable. Trusty has 11 packages by now, precise 39. I guess you might need some more of them.

Comment: Maybe your issue has already been fixed: https://launchpadlibrarian.net/176768751/qgis_2.2.0-2~trusty1_2.2.0-3%2Btrusty1.diff.gz `+   * fix python-pyspatialite dependency on trusty` but I'm not sure about other dependencies.

Comment: Update: trusty now has 17 packages. The libgdal-ecw is still missing. Most other QGIS related things work ok now with ubuntugis unstable.